# Detecting deformed lines

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I've already asked this question on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ but didn't get any answer! hope to get any suggestion here:

I have a project in which I have to recognize 2 lines in different "position", the lines are orthogonal but can be projected on different surfaces. I'm using opencv.

The intersection can be anywhere on the frame. The lines are red (the images show just the gray scale).

**UPDATE**

-I'll be using a gray scale camera !!!!!!!!!

-the background and objects on which the lines will be projected can change
[image: ilnes on straight surface]

[image: deformed lines]

**I'm not asking for  code**, but only for hints about how can I solve this? I tried `houghlines` function but it works only for straight surfaces. 
thanks in advance !

Comment: Is there any other property of these lines? Is the intersection point near the centre of the picture? Are they always white?

Comment: Are the lighting conditions really as bad as shown in the second picture? The problem is that your lines are not straight, not continuous and don´t have a different color than the background. If you can do anything about these conditions (e.g. add a black cardboard as background) this would hugely improve image quality and would make the line recognition easier.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal No the intersection can be anywhere on the frame any the lines are red  it's just the  gray scale

Comment: @Mailerdaimon I can't influence the background, it could be anything !! I know it only makes things worse ! but how can detected them if the there deformed ?

Comment: @Engine could you please describe your setup more precisely? This would have avoided the confusion about whether or not we can use color information to detect the lines.

Comment: @Mailerdaimon sorry about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not that difficult task as it include straight line. I have done similar kind of project.

1. First of all if your image is colored covert it to gray scale.
2. Then use a calibrated median filter to blur the image.
3. Now subtract the blurred image from the gray scale image.
4. After step 3 if you look at the image you will see that the on the places of lines the intensity 
   is higher than the other parts of image because these line are contrasted and when we apply median 
   filter the subtracted value is more than the rest of image.
5. to get a cleaner distinction you need to use create a binary image ie. only black and white with
   a particular thresh hold.
   6.Finally you got yu lines if their is noise you can use top hat filtering after step 4 and
   gaussian filtering after step 5.

You can take help from [this paper on crack detection](http://www.iaarc.org/publications/fulltext/P2-20.pdf)

Comment: This might work. One problem i see is that there are Regions in the image where there is no contrast at all between the light an the object(e.g. left side of the hand). This could result in finding only line segments which have to be connected afterwards. But it looks like a good starting point.

Comment: thanks @AMI i working on your suggestion I have one problem: I'm mot allowed to smooth the image !

Comment: Yeah that might take some work. do not use leniar median filter use a matrix median filter. and calibrate accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think AMI's idea is good.

You can also think about using controled laser source. In that case you can get image pair one with laser turned on and one with turned off, then find difference.

It can be interesting for you: http://www.instructables.com/id/3-D-Laser-Scanner/

Comment: indeed I think  AMI'S suggestion  makes sense I'm working on it

Answer (score 0):

Here's the result of subtracting the output of a median filter (r=6):

[image: result of subtracting a median-filtered image]

You might be able to improve things a bit by adjusting the median filter radius, but these wavy, discontinuous lines are going to be difficult to detect reliably.

You really need better source images. Here are a few suggestions:

1. A colour camera would help enormously. Apply a high-pass filter to the red and green channels, and calculate the difference between the two. The red lines will stand out much better then.
2. Can you make the light source brighter?
3. Have you tried putting a red filter over the camera lens? Ideally you want one with a pass band that matches the light source's wavelength as closely as possible — if the light is coming from a laser, then a suitable [dichroic filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichroic_filter) should give good results. But even a sheet of red plastic would be better than nothing. (Have you got an old pair of red/blue 3D glasses sitting around somewhere?)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps subtracting the grayscale image from the red channel would help to highlight the red. I'd post this as a comment but cannot do so yet.